# Quadratic Formula c++ - user-defined function

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions

I wrote this code with a user-defined function, but it seems not to work. I've trying to find out where the mistake is for hours. But couldn't find anything. it looks like the problem is in passing the parameter. But I don't know, I'm pretty new to this!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double solutionFun (double a, double b, double c) {

  double  delta, solution1, solution2;

  delta = b*b - 4*a*c;

  if (delta > 0 ){
    solution1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
    solution2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);

    cout << "There are 2 solutions." << endl;
    cout << "The solutions are:";
    return solution1, solution2;
  }

  else if (delta == 0){
    solution1 = (-b) / (2*a);
    cout << "There is 1 solution." << endl;
    cout << "The solution is:";
    return solution1;
  }

  else {
    cout << "There is no solution.";
    return 0;
  }

}

int main(){

  double a ,b ,c;

  cout << "Please enter the values of a, b, and c respectively:";
  cin >> a ,b ,c;

  solutionFun(a ,b ,c);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input did you give it? what result did you get? what result did you ***expect*** to get?

Comment: additionally, you don't want to use == to compare floating point numbers.

Comment: print the values a, b, and c.  Are they what you entered?

Comment: @MFisherKDX -- "you don't want to use ==" -- sure you do. It's exactly what's needed here. If `delta` is **exactly 0** there is **exactly 1**solution.

Comment: Your function has a **single** `double` as the return type.  So, what do you expect `return solution1, solution2;` to do?

Comment: What did you learn when you stepped through your program in your debugger and inspected the control flow and variable values? How, and where, did the actual behaviour differ from your expectations? Aka *debugging step 1*.

Comment: @MFisherKDX: I'm not stating anything about checking.  All I'm saying is that the `return` statement should have one value not two.  The *comma operator* will evaluate the first variable then return the second.  The `return` statement will not return two values.  I don't see where I made comments about comparisons in these comments.

Comment: @Pete Becker -- I really don't want to turn this into an argument. I get your point. And I don't think there is anything necessarily "wrong" here with checking == 0. But I think it's important for newbies to understand they should not expect == to "work" for floating point values. I've seen too many bugs from very bright developers who did not learn this. For instance you enter 1.0 0.2 0.01 for a, b, and c, you will get two roots instead of 1.

Comment: @AlexWatson:  You could make your program more efficient by assigning `sqrt(delta)` to a constant temporary variable and `2 * a` to a temporary variable before your first `if` statement.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Yes you'll get two roots instead of one, but you are not *really* entering those values, [don't you](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7UMHZZtJce8lETN2) ;)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not how you get multiple inputs:

```
cin >> a ,b ,c;
```

Instead, you want:

```
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

---

This code is not how you display answers:

```
cout << "The solutions are:";
return solution1, solution2;
```

Instead you want:

```
cout << "The solutions are:" << solution1 << " and also " << solution2;
```

Comment: So why is `solutionFun()` defined to return `double`?

Answer (score 3):

A few issues with regards to code validity and desired behavior (coding practice/design aside):

1. See how to return multiple values from your `solutionFun()` (currently defined to return `double`) by using `std::vector` -- even though you are not using anything returned in this piece of code.
2. You didn't print (`cout <<`) the solution values themselves, and it seemed like you were going for it.
3. See how to use `std::cin` for multiple inputs in one line of code.

---

A fixed version -- with respect to the above points:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<double> solutionFun (double a, double b, double c) {

  double  delta, solution1, solution2;

  delta = b*b - 4*a*c;

  if (delta > 0 ){
    solution1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
    solution2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);

    cout << "There are 2 solutions." << endl;
    cout << "The solutions are: " << solution1 << " and " << solution2;
    return {solution1, solution2};
  }

  else if (delta == 0){
    solution1 = (-b) / (2*a);
    cout << "There is 1 solution." << endl;
    cout << "The solution is: " << solution1;
    return {solution1};
  }

  else {
    cout << "There is no solution.";
    return {};
  }    
}

int main(){

  double a ,b ,c;

  cout << "Please enter the values of a, b, and c respectively:";
  cin >> a >> b >> c;

  auto result = solutionFun(a ,b ,c);

  for (auto scalar : result)
  {
    // Do something with a component, or don't return anything from the function : )
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is pass your `solution` variables on the command line:

```
void solutionFun (double a, double b, double c,
                  double& solution1, double& solution2, size_t& solution_count) {

  double  delta;

  delta = b*b - 4*a*c;
  solution2 = 0.0;

  if (delta > 0 ){
    solution1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
    solution2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
    solution_count = 2;

    cout << "There are 2 solutions." << endl;
    cout << "The solutions are: " << solution1 << " and " << solution2;
    return;
  }

  else if (delta == 0){
    solution1 = (-b) / (2*a);
    solution_count = 1;
    cout << "There is 1 solution." << endl;
    cout << "The solution is: " << solution1;
    return;
  }

  else {
    cout << "There is no solution.";
    solution_count = 0;
    return;
  }    
}
```

The `solution1, solution2` and `solution_count` are passed *by reference* which means that the function can modify the caller's variables.